# Encountering an error when I try to send an email to multiple people in python

Tags: python

I'm working with the below code to send emails to people in python.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart, MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate

    def send_mail(send_from,send_to, subject, text, files=[], server = "localhost"):
        for s in send_to:
               COMMASPACE = ', '
               msg = MIMEMultipart()
               msg['From'] = send_from
               msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(s)
               msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
               msg['Subject'] = subject

               msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

               for f in files:
                       part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                       part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
                       Encoders.encode_base64(part)
                       part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' %os.path.basename(f))
                       msg.attach(part)

               server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
               server.sendmail(send_from, s, msg.as_string())
               server.close()
```

Sorry for the formatting if it's messed up. emails is a pre-defined list with two emails. The error I'm encountering is:
        AttributeError: SMTP instance has no attribute 'find'

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste your full traceback and the complete code (including how you are calling it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a separate email message for each recipient; just send a single message with multiple recipients:

```
def send_mail(send_from,send_to, subject, text, files=[], server = "localhost"):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = send_from
   msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)

   # ... 

   server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
   server.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
   server.close()
```

This is almost identical to the example "Here’s an example of how to send a MIME message containing a bunch of family pictures that may be residing in a directory" in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html).

(If you don't want each person to see the other's addresses, you can make them all `BCC`s instead of `To`s.)

If you're more interested in what's wrong with your original code, than with how to do it properly, there are two immediately visible problems:

1. You're `join`ing each address, as Vader explains.
2. You're passing a single address as a string as the second argument to [`SMTP.sendmail`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), but the second argument is a sequence of addresses. To fix that, use `[s]` instead of `s`, as most of the examples do.

Both of these are caused by the same confusion, treating each address as a list of addresses. You may have additional errors caused by the same problem.

Comment: Thanks man. I just took out my for loop and used the list in the sendmail and it worked fine. Kinda proud I figured it out before I checked here. :) Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
>>> COMMASPACE = ', '
>>> send_to = ('test@example.com','test2@example.com')
>>> for s in send_to:
...  print COMMASPACE.join(s)
...
t, e, s, t, @, e, x, a, m, p, l, e, ., c, o, m
t, e, s, t, 2, @, e, x, a, m, p, l, e, ., c, o, m
```

and here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
    >>> COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    'test@example.com, test2@example.com'
```

Comment: This is _a_ problem, its not the problem though.